# Kafka is running on Openshift, The age of pods is 14 hrs. It means kafka application went down and restarted 14 hrs back?

Tags: apache-kafka, openshift-origin

I am a beginner in kafka and openshift. My kafka application is running on openshift.

when checked the pods status today i saw the below age and restarts.

```
 Name                         Status  Containers Ready  Container Restarts  Age
kafka-strimzi-dev-kafka-0     Running   2/2     0       14 hours
kafka-strimzi-dev-zookeeper-0 Running   2/2     0       14 hours
kafka-strimzi-dev-kafka-1     Running   2/2     0       14 hours
kafka-strimzi-dev-entity-operator Running   3/3     0       14 hours
kafka-strimzi-dev-kafka-2     Running   2/2     0       16 hours
strimzi-cluster-operator      Running   1/1     1       18 hours
kafka-strimzi-dev-zookeeper-1 Running   2/2     0       18 hours
kafka-strimzi-dev-zookeeper-2 Running   2/2     0       18 hours
```

i will check the stats daily per day and today while checking i saw the stats not showing fully.

[image: Stats]

When i checked the each pod terminal uptime it is showing 25 days.

I don't understand the difference between checking uptime of each pod in terminal and age of each pod showing as some hours.

Does this age indicates any restart happened to the kafka instances and does it impacts kafka application, consumers and publishers at that time?
No idea on this and any action needs to be taken further.

Comment: Can you please clarify what command you used from pod terminal UI to check the time which is showing 25d ago ?

Comment: Hi Chandra,Thanks for the response. I have checked”uptime”command. When I checked with developer he told due to some updates restarted Openshift and I have observed in the logs Kafka application and pods are down that time. Now my doubt is if the pod terminal is like server of that pod( Kafka broker) when pod restarted means why the uptime is 25 days in each terminal for that respective pods.I am not understanding the difference if application is down means the Kafka broker running on pod also went down and restarted so the terminal uptime also it should show 14 hours.Could you please explain